# Laravel Eager Loading, multiple same hasOne relations

Tags: php, laravel-5, eloquent

I have 2 simple models. First, one is called Builds and the second one is called SlotOptions. Each build can have like 5 assigned slots.

```
class BuildDB extends Model
```

And has 5 such relations `slot1-5 and id changes to slot1-5_id`

```
 public function slot1()
    {
        return $this->hasOne('\App\SlotOptions', 'id', 'slot1_id');
    }
```

In the controller I call it such way;

```
BuildDB::with([ 'slot1', 'slot2', 'slot3', 'slot4', 'slot5'])->find(5);
```

`\App\SlotOptions` model doesn't contain any extra coding.

This generates 5 "same" queries. - atm the eager loading would work if I get a list of builds and each slot would have whereIn clause, is it possible to have it a one big `wherein` the clause,  or does it require to change the DB schema.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not possible to optimize eager loading in this case.

I recommend that you change your database schema to a [many-to-many relationship](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Many-to-many_(data_model)).
This design is more flexible, it allows you to easily add more slots in the future.

Create a pivot table named `build_slot_option` with these columns: `build_id`, `slot_option_id`
Add an additional column if you want to number/order the slots.

Then define a [`BelongsToMany`](https://laravel.com/docs/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many) relationship:

```
class BuildDB extends Model
{
    public function slots()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(
            SlotOptions::class, 'build_slot_option', 'build_id', 'slot_option_id'
        );
    }
}

BuildDB::with('slots')->find(5);
```

Comment: You should have mentioned that you are using MongoDB. This answer really only applies to SQL databases.

Comment: Please create a new question.

Comment: Sure, If you feel like helping https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55148861/belongstomany-hybrid-relation, Ill upvote this and accept, since was just partially working, in SQL databases.