# belongsToMany, hybrid relation

Tags: php, laravel, jenssegers-mongodb

I have 2 simple models. First, one is called Builds (mysql) and the second one is called SlotOptions (mongodb). Each build can have 5 assigned slots. Based on https://stackoverflow.com/a/55132863/2513428

```
select * from `builds` where `builds`.`id` = 37 limit 1
SlotOptions.find({"heroName":{"$in":[37]}},{"typeMap":{"root":"array","document":"array"}})
```

Table. **build_slot_option**  (mysql)

```
+----------------+--------+----------------------------------------+
|      Name      |  Type  |                  Desc                  |
+----------------+--------+----------------------------------------+
| slot_option_id | char50 | // FK, Name of slot option f.e "Hero1" |
| build_id       | int    | // FK, Build id                        |
| pos            | int    | // Number 1-5                          |
+----------------+--------+----------------------------------------+
```

slot_option_id - is a string that contains a hero name, it's not an ID in fact.

**Example**:

```
+----------------+----------+-----+
| slot_option_id | build_id | pos |
+----------------+----------+-----+
| Hero1          |       37 |   1 |
| Hero2          |       37 |   2 |
| Hero3          |       37 |   3 |
| Hero4          |       37 |   4 |
| Hero5          |       37 |   5 |
+----------------+----------+-----+
```

Table. **Builds** (mysql)

```
+------+------+------------------------+
| Name | Type |          Desc          |
+------+------+------------------------+
| id   | int  | // PK, of Builds Table |
| ...  | ...  | // and other columns   |
+------+------+------------------------+
```

This is the build class, and usage example.

```
 class BuildDB extends Model
{
    use HybridRelations;
    protected $connection = 'mysql';
    public function slots()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(
            SlotOptions::class, 'build_slot_option', 'build_id', 'slot_option_id'
        );
    }
}

BuildDB::with('slots')->find(5);
```

When it comes to the second query it should **not insert the build id** there `{"$in":[37]}` just all the slot names, from tb *build_slot_option* *slot_option_id* column. For example `{"$in":['Hero1','Hero2']}`